# Data ingestion testing

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, etl

In one of my project that I am working on, data source is a file and the data in file has to be copied in [Impala](https://impala.apache.org/) (Hadoop). 
Development work is already done and I need to figure out a testing strategy for this one. 
Are there any tool in market that can help in this ?
Also, is this similar to ETL testing ?

Answer (score 1):

From the Impala website I read it supports [ODBC](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_odbc.html) and SQL, so you could use regular database tools to help with manual or automated testing.

Sounds like an ETL process. You have an extracted file from somewhere, you have an application that transforms and loads it into an Impala datastore.

Comment: I am not very familiar with the ETL process or tools. Any suggestions ?